# Hadoop file system commands not found

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.6.0 on my laptop which runs Ubuntu 14.04 lts.

Below  is the link I followed for Hadoop installation: https://github.com/ev2900/YouTube_Vedio/blob/master/Install%20Hadoop%202.6%20on%20Ubuntu%2014.04%20LTS/Install%20Hadoop%202.6%20--%20Virtual%20Box%20Ubuntu%2014.04%20LTS.txt

After installation, I ran two commands:

1. `hadoop namenode -format` - It works fine
2. `hadoop fs -ls` - It is giving the following error

   15/11/15 16:15:28 WARN
   util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your
   platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

   ls: `.': No such file or directory

   help me  solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

`15/11/15 16:15:28 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable` is a perpetual annoyance and not an error, so don't worry about that.

The `ls: '.': No such file or directory` error means that you haven't made your home directory yet, so you're trying to `ls` on a folder that doesn't exist. Do the following (as HDFS root user) to create your home folder. Ensure it has the correct permissions (which I guess depends on what specifically you want to do re: groups etc):

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/'your-username'
```

Comment: i tried hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hduser but it showing the same error like mkdir: `/user/hduser': No such file or directory

Comment: Are you the HDFS root user?

Comment: Are you sure that /user/ exists?

Comment: this should solve the problem, or try to put some files in hdfs and run the fs -ls command again

Comment: i had some error in bashrc file i solved that  and after that i am getting this error now for     hadoop fs -ls command ls: Call From dell/127.0.1.1 to localhost:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused